# Is it possible to cache the compiled code from Babel standalone?

Tags: babeljs

Strongly suspecting the answer is no, it would be a nice feature to be able to cache the compiled code from Babel standalone, so that the browser only compiles the code once (until the source changes). Possible?

Example:

```html
<script type="text/babel">
// React component made with JSX. Can it be cached as it is *after* compilation with Babel?
</script>
```

Comment: You probably have to provide more context. It's should be easy to wrap babel in a memoization function yourself.

Comment: @FelixKling See my added example.

Comment: Well, in that case the answer is probably indeed "no". But including Babel/React code this way is also not recommended. Why are you doing it this way?

Comment: @FelixKling Well, why is it not recommended? Because of performance? If yes, then caching the browser-compiled code could be a solution.

Comment: *"If yes, then caching the browser-compiled code could be a solution."* To some degree. The user still has to download the actual build tool either way (which is probably cached at some point as well, but still). Why put the burden of building the code on the user? I don't quite know how the JSX in the browser conversion works, but if you can control it then you can still build a caching layer around it.